# filter IN and OUT punch timings for Attendance in Day and Night shifts in oracle SP?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, time-and-attendance

I am developing Attendance system which having day and night shift I am unable to filter the IN and OUT punches of the employees? below is my current logic.

shift timings on 29-Jun-2015 IN 22:00 OUT 07:00 and on 30-Jun-2015 IN 15:00 OUT 22:30

I am filtering the IN and OUT punches based on shift timings and swipe time along with date, but when the employee changing from night shift to day shift I am getting problem.
the below is the one scenario
the employee : 101 has worked on 29-Jun-2015 on night shift punched at 22:00 and he left at next day means 30-Jun-2015 07:00 AM and again the same day (30-Jun-2015) he came to office at 15:00 on 30-Jun-2015 and he left at 22:30 on the same day.

In this case how can I get IN and OUT tomes for both dates?

Sample Data

[image]

Employee No 60 and 61 shift time 8 AM to 5 PM.
Employee No 70 shift time 6 PM to 3 AM.

Comment: Is the problem that the OUT time doesn't have a date component? In which case you could maybe infer that when the OUT time is smaller than the IN time it must be the next day?

Comment: No. I'm getting minimum time for a date as IN TIME and maximum time for a date as OUT TIME. But when shift swipe between 2 days what can I do.

Comment: Please show us a sample of your table and data.

Comment: Added sample data to question.

Comment: Why does the date format change? What does the time format 6.00 and 6.02 mean?

Comment: Oh, and what if someones misses a timestamp?

Comment: 6.00 and 6.02 means 6 AM and 6.02  AM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83828/discussion-between-tom-and-rene).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done looking just at the data per date. For example employee 60 we have time of:

6:00
9:00
12:00

This could mean anything. Maybe if you can use more knowledge, for example the normal shift start and end times and shift duration.

If nobody ever misses a clock punch then you can sort the entries on date+time per employee. Odd numbered entries are IN and even entries are OUT. But you better get your data in a date column because the sample you have given looks like string data to me.

Comment: I can consider Odd numbered entries are IN and even entries are OUT.But if employee shift span to 2 days is this logic correct?

Comment: For a example if there is punch at 1.00 AM today and if that is OUT for that employee, according to above logic still that will consider as IN. Because for today that is the first time punch.